# How to associate the elements of a list to numbers?

Tags: associations

I am having problems to understand the association function. 
I have a list of lists containing numbers:

```
{{{0.494118, 0.678431, 0.882353, 1.}, {0.498039, 0.682353, 0.886275, 
   1.}, {0.505882, 0.686275, 0.882353, 1.}, {0.509804, 0.690196, 
   0.886275, 1.}, {0.521569, 0.694118, 0.886275, 1.}, {0.529412, 
   0.694118, 0.890196, 1.}, {0.533333, 0.698039, 0.886275, 
   1.}, {0.537255, 0.701961, 0.890196, 1.},...}}
```

and I would like something like this:

```
{{{0.494118, 0.678431, 0.882353, 1.}->1, {0.498039, 0.682353, 0.886275, 
   1.}->2, {0.505882, 0.686275, 0.882353, 1.}->3...}}
```

then, the final output should be `{1,2,3,...}`.

Could you please tell me which functions should I consider to get the final output?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {{0.494118, 0.678431, 0.882353, 1.}, {0.498039, 0.682353, 
    0.886275, 1.}, {0.505882, 0.686275, 0.882353, 1.}, {0.509804, 
    0.690196, 0.886275, 1.}, {0.521569, 0.694118, 0.886275, 
    1.}, {0.529412, 0.694118, 0.890196, 1.}, {0.533333, 0.698039, 
    0.886275, 1.}, {0.537255, 0.701961, 0.890196, 1.}};

Thread[list -> Range@Length@list]
```

> {{0.494118, 0.678431, 0.882353, 1.} -> 
>     1, {0.498039, 0.682353, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     2, {0.505882, 0.686275, 0.882353, 1.} -> 
>     3, {0.509804, 0.690196, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     4, {0.521569, 0.694118, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     5, {0.529412, 0.694118, 0.890196, 1.} -> 
>     6, {0.533333, 0.698039, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     7, {0.537255, 0.701961, 0.890196, 1.} -> 8}

Comment: Many thanks, OkkesDulgerci!

Answer (score 3):

You can also use [`MapIndexed`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapIndexed.html):

```
MapIndexed[# -> #2[[1]] &, list]
```

> {{0.494118, 0.678431, 0.882353, 1.} -> 1,
>    {0.498039, 0.682353, 0.886275, 1.} ->   2,
>   {0.505882, 0.686275, 0.882353, 1.} -> 
>     3,
>   {0.509804, 0.690196, 0.886275, 1.} ->   4,
>    {0.521569, 0.694118, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     5,
>   {0.529412, 0.694118, 0.890196, 1.} ->   6,
>   {0.533333, 0.698039, 0.886275, 1.} -> 
>     7,
>    {0.537255, 0.701961, 0.890196, 1.} -> 8}